# Angular Observable emitting as many events as I have subscribers

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Having trouble understanding angular observable. 
I am creating an observable which emits an random number once.
I have 2 subscribers I am getting two different numbers.
If I have 3 subscribers, I get 3 different numbers.
I know with `observable` we get only 1 number.

```js
const observable = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
  observer.next(Math.random());
});
  
// subscription 1
observable.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('Observer Subscriber A:', data); 
});
  
// subscription 2
observable.subscribe((data) => {
 console.log('Observer Subscriber B:', data); 
});

// subscription 3
observable.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('Observer Subscriber C:', data); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

How is it emitting as many events as I have subscribers?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `share()` operator to multicast the values.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html

```
const observable = Observable.create((observer) => {
  observer.next(Math.random());
}).pipe(share());
```

The observer function is executed every a subscriber attaches to the observable. The *share* operator subscribes and creates a new observable that will emit the last value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BehaviorSubject instead.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;

const observable$ = new BehaviorSubject(Math.random());

observable$.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('Observer Subscriber A:', data); 
});

// subscription 2
observable$.subscribe((data) => {
 console.log('Observer Subscriber B:', data); 
});

// subscription 3
observable$.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('Observer Subscriber C:', data); 
});

observable$.next(Math.random());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

BehaviorSubjects are the reactive developers best friend.